# Cardinality weird result, x5 the good result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, cardinality

I have a weird result with `cardinality` aggregation on elasticsearch 2.4,
I have 10 documents, but when i do:

```
GET /test-dev/page_view/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "user_count": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "cookie",
                "precision_threshold": 40000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result is:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 10,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "user_count": {
            "value": 15
        }
    }
}
```

and it should be 3, is it because I have 3 shards and 2 replica so I have to divide the result by 5?

Comment: Why it should be 3? Also, what's the mapping definition for the `cookie` field?

Comment: Because i inserted it, cookie is a string

Comment: Right. So, you inserted 10 documents and all these 10 have 3 unique values for `cookie`. Correct?

Comment: what's the mapping definition for the cookie field?

Comment: Exactly, sorry i dont no what is a mapping ?

Comment: You can find the mapping of the index with `GET /test-dev/page_view/_mapping`

Comment: Also, since this is 5.x and you didn't change the mapping in any way, you probably can use this as well in your query: `"cardinality" : {
          "field" : "cookie.keyword",
          "precision_threshold": 40000
        }`

Comment: Cookie type is : `"cookie": {
                  "type": "string"
               },` i do not understand why i have this result

Comment: Then it needs to be `"index"": "not_analyzed"`. In 5.x though, there is the type `keyword` for this purpose.

Comment: Oh sorry, i just check and my cluster is in 2.4, but it's like it is the same api related to the documentation

Comment: The search will work the way you want it if the indexing works the way it needs to be. That's why you need `"index": "not_analyzed"` as I mentioned.

Comment: you should post that in responce, i will accept it, thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cookie` field should be `"index": "not_analyzed"` otherwise the field will be split into tokens and it will not be kept as a whole and match exactly your cookie.